# How to avoid click event in a switch button

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anybody know, is there a way to avoid the click event when using a switch button ? I mean, I want to change the state just when sliding the finger.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a method inherited from _android.widget.CompoundButton_ named __performClick()__. You can override this function just returning true and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ok,in that case you can `View` instead of `Button` and set `OnSwipeTouchListener` to `View`

**OnSwipeTouchListener.java**

```
 public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        }

        private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                boolean result = false;
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                onSwipeRight();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                        }
                        result = true;
                    } 
                    else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffY > 0) {
                                onSwipeBottom();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeTop();
                            }
                        }
                        result = true;

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
        }

        public void onSwipeTop() {
        }

        public void onSwipeBottom() {
        }
    }
```

And in your Activity

```
yourview.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
       //actions on slide/swipe
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```